# How to get the memory size of an Julia DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, memory, julia, size

I would like to optimize (the columns in) a Julia DataFrame. To do so, I would like to get the size of the the DataFrame before and after an optimization.

Here's an example DataFrame:

```
rows, columns = 10_000, 50
df = rand([x for x in "ABCDE"], rows, columns) |> DataFrame
```

The size of this `df` object...

```
sizeof(df)
```

The size is 24.

However, when I sum the sizes of the columns, the size is diffferent...

```
sum([sizeof(df[x]) for x in names(df)])
```

The sum of the column sizes is 2000000.

Here's the optimization...

```
for i = names(df)
    df[i] = CategoricalArray(df[i], ordered=false)
end
```

Results are:

```
sizeof(df)
```

The size is 24.

```
sum([sizeof(df[x]) for x in names(df)])
```

The sum of the column sizes is 800.

Any suggestions how to get an accurate size of an DataFrame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how a way how you can do it:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(rand([x for x in "ABCDE"], rows, columns), :auto);

julia> Base.summarysize(df)
2007456

julia> Base.summarysize(mapcols(PooledArray, df)) # this will change in the next release of PooledArrays.jl as the default size of refarray element will be UInt32
525656

julia> Base.summarysize(mapcols(categorical, df))
2037256

julia> Base.summarysize(mapcols(x -> categorical(x, compress=true), df))
534856
```

Note though that in this case it is not much, as all your columns have `Char` element type. You would get much more benefit if had columns holding long strings.